# Polar Equation area

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The graph of
$r = \frac{4}{2 - \cos \theta}$
forms a closed curve. The area of the region inside the curve can be expressed in the form $k \pi$. What is $k^2$?

How would I do this? I have tried to convert it to rectangular form, and got $r=\frac{x+4}{2}$, but I don't know what to do from here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Narasimham's answer is perfectly fine, but just to add something interesting, by following [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Polar_form_relative_to_focus) you will learn that your equation is the equation of an ellipse with:
$$ a(1-e^2) = 2,\qquad e=\frac{1}{2}, $$
so with semi-axis $a=\frac{8}{3},b=\frac{4\sqrt{3}}{3}$ and area:
$$ A = \pi a b = \frac{32\sqrt{3}}{9}\pi, $$
so $\color{red}{k^2=\frac{1024}{27}}.$

Answer (score 1):

Use the polar coordinate formula directly and integrate:

$$ A = \frac12 \int r^2 d \theta $$